# Refresh bean in spring with interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have developed a springMVC application which uses ehcache. The cache items are fetched from another system. I would not know when will the items get change in the next system. I need to periodically trigger a webservice call say 5 hrs or 3 hrs interval in order to fetch the changed items and update in the cache.

Is it possible to refresh to bean in paricular interval so that upon refreshing i will invoke the webservices and refresh the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to solve your problem is to create a periodically executed job that triggers the WebService call.

Something like this:

```
@Service
public class WebServiceRefreshService {

  public static final int SERVICE_CALL_RATE_MILLISECONDS = 60 * 1000;

 @Scheduled(fixedRate = SERVICE_CALL_RATE_MILLISECONDS)
    public void refreshFromWebService() {
      //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Just registering it as a bean is enough to start the schedule or we need to invoke ?

Comment: if you're managing your context with annotations, it's plug-and-play :). Just include this code into one of your component-scan packages and it will be automatically executed